# Transparent proxying, not affecting other traffic

Tags: proxy, squid

I want configure the system as following:

- There are several web app servers, each of which have global IP addresses.
- The web app servers make HTTP and HTTPS requests to several (unidentified) external services. The source IP address of packets (thus destination port 80/tcp or 443/tcp) need to be fixed to a global IP address, so **actually I need transparent proxy for HTTP/HTTPS, not affecting other traffic**.
- Other packets should not use the global IP address above, but should use global IP addresses that the server is each assigned.
- The web application is very old and it's impossible to modify it to use proxy (CONNECT) protocol.

So I tried to use iptables to DNAT from 80/tcp and 443/tcp to the squid proxy on all web servers, and configured squid as an interception proxy.
However I failed it by redirection loop error.
I investigated what squid is doing by strace and found that it tries to connect to 10.0.0.252:80 after receiving a request, and therefore forwarding loop is detected.

I believe it is because of misconfiguration but I have no idea which should be fixed, or maybe totally I misunderstand what I should do.
(I googled but couldn't find the examples that NAT on each server.)

Hope could someone help solve the problem, or suggest another better way (not limited to using squid proxy)

All servers are on Amazon EC2, so it is a choice to use a vyos for a router...

---

ip a result on squid proxy

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:1c:ba:c3:9c:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.211/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::81c:baff:fec3:9c1d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:a9:2c:5e:eb:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.252/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8a9:2cff:fe5e:ebd7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

iptables on squid proxy

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.252 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.252:3129
```

iptables on web servers

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.252:80
```

cache.log

```
2016/06/22 06:15:22 kid1| WARNING: Forwarding loop detected for:
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: squidclient/3.5.19
Accept: */*
Via: 1.0 unknown (squid/3.5.19)
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.0.211
Cache-Control: max-age=259200
Connection: keep-alive
Host: ifconfig.moe
```

Full squid.conf

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

#http_access deny to_localhost

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

visible_hostname unknown

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128
http_port 3129 intercept
http_port 3130 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/myCA.pem

always_direct allow all

ssl_bump none localhost
ssl_bump server-first all

# temporary: just test
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER

http_access deny all
```

Answer (score 1):

If you DNAT to the proxy, you're changing the destination to the IP of the proxy.  In this case, the proxy will lose the information about the original destination.

For http this is ok, since the host header can be used to resolve the target, but for https the proxy would need to rely on SNI in the TLS ClientHello packet to learn the target and connect to it, bootstrap the TLS layer and go from there.

Comment: On only IP layer, it's true. But in this case I configured an interception proxy where the proxy can know what request to send not only by IP header but also by HTTP(S) request header. Actually, as I wrote in this question, squid tried to connect to the IP address in IP header, not resolving name from HTTP header.

Comment: there's a chicken and egg problem.  Until the TLS layer is set up, the client doesn't send any HTTP request, so there's no host header until after the TLS handshake.  The only thing with the server name is the SNI extension in the ClientHello packet.  If you DNAT you're changing the dest IP, so unless you're tunneling via the squid using IP-IP or similar, the destination is only in the SNI.  And you lose the port number - you;d need to DNAT to a different port on squid for each different port your router was DNATting.

Comment: An alternative is to use a proxy product that also does the TCP interception, such as our product WinGate.  In that case, the interceptor can communicate the original destination to the proxy out of band.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.